# Is there a way to make xdmp:ldap-search() function to use appserver external LDAP configuration

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

For my application, I use application level authentication, and for some users I want to fetch some information from the active directory.

I have setup an http server with an "external securities" configuration that I created for our active directory.

I attempted to use the function as follows:

```
let $res := xdmp:ldap-search( "(mail=abc@def.com)",  <options xmlns="xdmp:ldap">
                        <use-appserver-config>true</use-appserver-config>
                    </options> )
```

Unfortunately, this does not return anything although it should, nor does it give any error messages. However, if I explicitly specify the username, password, ldap server, etc. like below it works (well, for most cases, if the response does not contain an accented character):

```
let $res := xdmp:ldap-search( "(mail=abc@def.com)"
                    ,  <options xmlns="xdmp:ldap">
                        <username>{ $config:ldap-connection-username }</username>
                        <password>{ $config:ldap-connection-password }</password>
                        <server-uri>{ $config:ldap-connection-server }</server-uri>
                        <search-base>{ $config:ldap-connection-search-base }</search-base>
                    </options>)
```

Clearly, the option true does not work as I expected. But, it is also taken into account because if I set it to false, an error is returned.

I am sure that I set the values for the configured ldap server on the admin pages as identical to the one used in the working example above.

Is this a bug? Or, what am I missing?

thanks a lot,
K.

Comment: Hello.  Can you please explain where you are running your tests for the two sets of code above?  Query console or app server directly? If Query Console, please confirm that you are running the code in the context of the appropriate app server.

Comment: @DavidEnnis, thanks for looking. Yes, I tested both on qconsole (replaced the variables with hardcoded strings in the second case), and run under the the appserver that I configured the external security for.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be specific to running in QConsole under the app-server context. Specifying `<use-appserver-config>true</use-appserver-config>` results in no call being made out to the AD server and an empty result sequence. Running directly under the AppServer does return the expected results, I'll create a bug report for this.